# convert postgresql query to Native Query

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hql, recursive-query

**I want to convert the below postgresql query to hibernate
query or any type of query that supports in java**

```
WITH RECURSIVE  tree(parent, idElement) AS
    (
    --Anchor member definition
        SELECT  e.fk_course_det_id, e.course_det_id,e.course_name
        FROM course_details AS e   
        WHERE course_det_id =1
        UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member definition
        SELECT d.fk_course_det_id, d.course_det_id,d.course_name
        FROM tree 
        INNER JOIN course_details AS d
            ON tree.idElement = d.fk_course_det_id
            )
            SELECT *
    FROM tree
```

**I just converted the above query to native query**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "course_details")
    @NamedNativeQuery(
        name    =   "getAllChild",
      query=" WITH RECURSIVE  tree(idElement,parent,name) AS"+
    "("+

        " SELECT  e.course_det_id,e.fk_course_det_id,e.course_name"+
        " FROM course_details AS e "+
        " WHERE e.course_det_id =?1"+
       " UNION ALL"+

         " SELECT  d.course_det_id,d.fk_course_det_id,d.course_name"+
        " FROM tree "+
         " INNER JOIN course_details AS d"+
           " ON tree.idElement = d.fk_course_det_id"+
            " )"+
            " SELECT * FROM tree",
   resultClass=CourseDetails.class
)
    @Component
    public class CourseDetails{//
    ...//}
```

**in implementation class**

```
@Override
    public @ResponseBody List<CourseDetails> sectionList(@ModelAttribute("course_details_create") CourseDetails cd,
            @RequestParam("cdtype") Long cdtype, Model model) {

         List<CourseDetails> allList = entityManager.createNamedQuery("getAllChild", CourseDetails.class)
                 .setParameter(1, cdtype)
                 .getResultList();
return allList;
```

but i got the error 
**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name course_det_id was not found in this ResultSet.**

**Fullstacktrace**

```
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.findColumn(PgResultSet.java:2588) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.getLong(PgResultSet.java:2486) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:238) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:234) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:789) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:714) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:336) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1967) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:125) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
    at com.wudi.edu.service.impl.coursedetails.CourseDetailsServiceImpl.sectionList(CourseDetailsServiceImpl.java:64) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.wudi.edu.controller.rest.coursedetails.CourseDetailsRestController.sectionList(CourseDetailsRestController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.6.jar:8.5.6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Comment: I think you can't without write some JPA vendor specific function.But you can use native query and map to object: http://www.buzdin.lv/2012/08/recursive-polymorphic-queries-with-jpa.html

Comment: @Rodrigo Menezes  are you sure?

Comment: There are more information about this problem in some posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638082/recursive-jpa-query

Comment: @RodrigoMenezes iam really new to cte expressions and queries,can i achieve this using native queries??

Comment: HQL doesn't support such type of query, as mentioned you have to use Native Query to do so. And yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @RodrigoMenezes i just updated the question please check the situation

Comment: http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/query-complex-jpa-hibernate/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research,i just pass string sql query to native hibernate sqlquery
and i got the result perfectly as desired.

```
@Override
    public @ResponseBody List<CourseDetails> sectionList(@ModelAttribute("course_details_create") CourseDetails cd,
            @RequestParam("cdtype") Long cdtype, Model model) {

        Session session = getSession();
        String query = "WITH RECURSIVE  tree(parent, idElement) AS" + "(" +

                "SELECT  e.fk_course_det_id, e.course_det_id,e.course_name,e.course_desc,e.fk_book_id,e.fk_org_id"
                + " FROM course_details AS e" + " WHERE course_det_id =" + cdtype + " UNION ALL" +

                " SELECT d.fk_course_det_id, d.course_det_id,d.course_name,d.course_desc,d.fk_book_id,d.fk_org_id AS course_det_id"
                + " FROM tree" + "  INNER JOIN course_details AS d" + " ON tree.idElement = d.fk_course_det_id" + " )"
                + " SELECT *" + " FROM tree";

        SQLQuery qry = session.createSQLQuery(query);
        qry.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
        List<CourseDetails> results = qry.list();

        return results;

    }
```