# Recursive entities and hibernate + jpa for entity communication. Help me figure it out

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

A simple rest api application, where json of this format is received at the endpoint. Let's call the main object 'unload type', the enrich field in this object contains the same objects, in fact, the nesting can be deep. Using JdbcTemplate, I used my sql query and collected everything in the application, but this is a voluminous solution. I would like to bring everything to the hibernate level. How can I work with such nesting?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "SCHEMA_NAME",
    "isMandatory": "Y",
    "default": "",
    "description": "description more",
    "choose": [],
    "enrich": {},
    "exclude": {}
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "TABLE_NAME",
    "isMandatory": "Y",
    "default": "",
    "description": "description more",
    "choose": [
      "ARC",
      "INC"
    ],
    "enrich": {
      "INC": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "STAT_ID",
          "isMandatory": "Y",
          "default": "1",
          "description": "description more",
          "choose": [],
          "enrich": {},
          "exclude": {}
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "STAT_ENTITY_ID",
          "isMandatory": "Y",
          "default": "",
          "description": "description more",
          "choose": [],
          "enrich": {},
          "exclude": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    "exclude": {
      "FALSE": [
        "ISHEADERDEFAULT"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "SCHEMA_NAME",
    "isMandatory": "Y",
    "default": "",
    "description": "description more",
    "choose": [],
    "enrich": {},
    "exclude": {}
  }
]
```

I am waiting for help in the direction of a solution. Spring, hibernate + jpa, java.

Comment: Short answer is that neither Hibernate nor JPA  handle recursion.   If your database handles it (eg Oracle’s CONNECT BY ) you could use a native query.  Otherwise you could try the ideas here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639538/681444