# SQL to HQL 'start with' and 'Connect by Prior'

Tags: sql, grails, hql

I need to find a way to get the ids starting with 11, in sql is with 'start with' and 'Connect by prior' but in HQL, how can I do that?, if there is a better way in grails, the help would be great, thanks!

(Updated: Sorry, I didn't write the other command which is: 'connect by prior')

Comment: Do you mean something like `[offset: 10]` or `where id > 10`?

Comment: Oh. I had a third interpretation: the ID as a string starts with '11'. What exactly do you want.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the ID is a string, why not simply use a like clause:

```
where id like '11%'
```

Assuming it's not a string, you could cast it to a string:

```
where cast(id as STRING) like '11%'
```

or

```
where str(id) like '11%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean query for records with ids greater or equal to 11, then example if you have a table of Books, then the HQL would be

```
def books = Books.executeQuery("SELECT b from Books b WHERE id >= 11")
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive SQL queries are non-standard so HQL does not support them (although I found a [paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/v05v422450438477/) that appears to propose and prototype adding support). To do them you'll need to stick with SQL. Here's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486757/hql-recursion-how-do-i-do-this).