# Hibernate hql query syntax error

Tags: hibernate, hql

trying to execute this query :

```
public List<Product> getChildrenById(int id) {          
        String hql= " FROM Product"
                + " START WITH parent_id = ?"
            + " CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR  id = parent_id"
            + " ORDER SIBLINGS BY id"; 
        return (List<Product>) entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(1, id).getResultList();
    }
```

i got a syntax error:org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: WITH near line 1, column 44 [ FROM com.example.gmao.model.Product START WITH parent_id = ? CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR  id = parent_id ORDER SIBLINGS BY id];

any help? thx

Comment: my product class is defined as below: public class Product {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name="id")
 private int id;
 
 @Column(name="name")
 private String value;
 
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = true)

 private Set<Product> children = null;
 ..}

Comment: START WITH ... CONNECT BY is not [HQL query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html). This is a proprietary SQL syntax coming from Oracle Database and, as far as I know, it is supported by DB2 too. If you are using one of these  databases, you can use native queries (using `createSQLquery`, not `ceateQuery`). You can't do recursive queries directly in Hibernate/JPA, see [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486757/hql-recursion-how-do-i-do-this).

Comment: i'm working with informix db, the query is working fine but when used with hibernate it causes this error.

Comment: now it works, thx for your help !